# What is the reason why it stuck on the queued when using GetFile -> ExecuteScript (Python) in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

Flow: GetFile -> ExecuteScript

[image]

```python
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class PyStreamCallback(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    outputStream.write(bytearray('Hello World!'[::-1].encode('utf-8')))
  
flowFile = session.get()
if(flowFile != None):
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, PyStreamCallback())
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Queued cannot be removed and needs to restart before removing it.

Comment: the red flag at right-top of processor mean you have an error.

Comment: how to check the specific error under that processor?

Comment: hover red flag, or read in log file